# Set RTC Alarm from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, acpi, rtcwake

Linux has a nice utility rtcwake that sets RTC alarm. My PC can boot up from shutdown state using it so there's no problem there. But is there any way to make it possible on Windows? I found a similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1168177/wakealarm-for-windows) but it links to the dead program. Also it would be nice to have a cli way to do it.